# Tortoise SVN 1.8.8 doesn't include checkout?

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

I just downloaded TortoiseSVN from here: http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

It appears not to include the checkout command.

So when I right -click on a desktop folder and go to the TortoiseSVN contextual menu - Checkout is missing.

Is this a bug?

**Assumptions:**

- Windows 7
- 64 bit
- Tortoise SVN 1.8.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseSVN puts common options outside the TortoiseSVN sub-menu. They are directly in the main contextual menu.

[image]

You can change which options show up directly in the main menu. Right click, then go to TortoiseSVN > Settings > General > Context Menu > Cascaded.